# JS smooth transition between two value change

Tags: javascript

I have this variables changing constantly, from 0 to 100 this coming from an exernal SDK like this for example:

```
window.addEventListener({
 variable = 0; 
})
```

Now when this variable change and goes to another value it's too sharp for me and I want to make this exponential, for example,
not 0 => 100 directly, but I want to sample the value of variable every x millisecond e make a smooth transition between the two value with the intermediate value

example: 0 => 20 => 40 => 60 => 80 => 100

how can I do?

Comment: Are you changing the values or is the external SDK providing the changing value?

Comment: Please, provide a code snippet of how it's done now - so people here would have some context on where to start. Then, I'd suggest you need to make use of `setTimeout()` function.

Comment: Maybe it's an XY question: is this for a visual effect? maybe it can be done by the visual stuff (like CSS transition for HTML) instead of numerically (note also that your example numbers are not exponential, but i'm quibbling here)

Comment: @MTCoster the SDK change the value based on webcam analysis

Comment: In which case the current answer won’t help you - what you’re looking to do is called [**interpolation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation), adding extra data points between the existing ones. Your example (0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100) is specifically [**linear interpolation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)

Comment: @Kaddath no it's a value in the code not graphics, I use this value to change audio volume and other things so i need to smooth that

Comment: @MTCoster exact, interpolation between two values that constantly change. interpolation variable I use it as a value to change the volume of sound and the intensity of physical light with osc messages

Comment: Linear interpolation is impossible to achieve in true real time, because it requires the next value to calculate the gradient after the previous one. You’ll need to delay your output by one sample so you can calculate the gradient between each consecutive pair of input values and generate a stream of values along that gradient at a faster sampling rate

Comment: I don't think I have enough info to properly answer you, but i can give advices: you'll have to take account that smoothing will need a transition time, if the value changes again while transition is not finished, you'll have to stop transitioning, and start a new transition based on the intermediary value you reached. This may cause a real loss of accuracy between the real time signal and what you get, depending on changes time vs transition time, so that will need adjustements probably

Comment: if the value keeps changing so frequently (or at a totally unknown frequency?) that it would "interrupt" the animation in my answer, then you'd need to check for that and restart the animation with new parameters...or even calculate a different animation duration depending on the difference between the current value and the (new) end value.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var animationDuration = 500; //in miliseconds
var startValue = 0;
var endValue = 100;

function animateNextFrame(currentTime) {

    if (!startTime) startTime = currentTime;
    var elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime;

    if (elapsedTime < animationDuration) {

        currentValue = Math.floor((elapsedTime / animationDuration) * (endValue - startValue));

        //set your field value to currentValue here with something like document.getElemenById...

        //call the next animation frame
        window.requestAnimationFrame(animateNextFrame);

    } else {
        //set your field value to endValue here with something like document.getElemenById...
    }
}
//trigger the number animation
window.requestAnimationFrame(animateNextFrame);
```

Comment: Is `startTime` a global variable?